# Syntax Oracle error

Tags: oracle, syntax, ora-00904

```
SELECT LINE_NUMBER, time
FROM LINE
JOIN LINE_STOP  ON LINE.ID=LINE_STOP.LINE_ID
JOIN PASSAGE    ON LINE.STOP_ID = PASSAGE.LINE_STOP_ID
WHERE "time" =    (select count (*) as "time"
                        from passage 
                        where hours * 60 + minutes between 300 and 380);
```

I have an invalid identifier error ora-00904. In pretty sure it's because it did not recognise Time, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the layout of your tables and the exact error message you're seeing. Thanks.

Comment: `WHERE "time" = (...`

Answer (score 0):

Time is described in the official documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14354/appb.htm) as a word with
... "a special meaning to Oracle but are not reserved words and so can be redefined".

If you must use any of the words in the list you must double quote them and keep the case consistent with the case used at creation.

```
SELECT LINE_NUMBER, "TIME"
FROM LINE
JOIN LINE_STOP  ON LINE.ID=LINE_STOP.LINE_ID
JOIN PASSAGE    ON LINE.STOP_ID = PASSAGE.LINE_STOP_ID
WHERE "TIME" =    (select count (*) as "TIME"
                        from passage 
                        where hours * 60 + minutes between 300 and 380);
```